# Can a protein falling below a threshold trigger another response?

Tags: systems-biology

Is it possible that the falling of the concentration of a protein below a threshold triggers the release or production of another protein?

Comment: Welcome to SE Biology. Your question is very broad. You need to provide some context — is this a homework question or do you have a specific system in mind? Why are you asking this question and what attempts have you made to solve it yourself. See ["How do I ask a good question"](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Oh, and please spell-check your titles at least. I'll correct this one.

Comment: A: Yes. There are too many examples to list.

Answer (score 2):

Of course, that is possible. I'll give a simple example. If your protein (X) is an inhibitor of the other protein (Y), then when X falls, Y will rise. This would not really be "thresholded".

There are many mechanisms that can lead to thresholding which include co-operativity (in the action of X) and positive feedbacks. How these mechanisms work would be a different question altogether. (A quick read would be [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrasensitivity)).

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm a physicist and I'm interested in how axons can regulate its length. In a model I'm dealing with, the concrentration of a protein falls below a threshold when the axon reaches a distinct length. The question is if this falling below the threshold can stop the axon from growing.

Comment: @Peter123 As I mentioned above, it is possible. If you are asking an example of what those proteins X and Y may be in case of axon growth then I think you should do that literature mining yourself. There may be several examples. Check out a review on this topic.